# How to sort a pandas dataframe by multiple colums (1 string and 1 number)

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, sorting, integer

I want to sort my pandas dataframe based on a value in the Duration column while also making sure that in the Event column the failure comes first if duration numbers are equal. See below:

```py
        Time    Event  Duration
11    220.69  failure     12.92
90   1913.28       PM     14.59
43    955.89  failure     14.59
```

In this case I want to makes sure that index 43 comes before index 90 because I want to have failures before PM when durations are equal. How can I do this?

```py
machine_data.sort_values(by=['Duration', 'Event'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

I already tried this but I still gives me the same result (see below)

```py
11    220.69  failure     12.92
90   1913.28       PM     14.59
43    955.89  failure     14.59
```

Comment: Your code works fine. It sorts index 43 before index 90. Are you sure the Durations are equal (maybe `round(2)` to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mozway you most likely need to round the durations in order for them to be regarded as equal. However there is a second potential source of problems in your code. As it is, it is currently deppending on the lexicographical order of words to correctly order. If you add a third event type this may no longer be possible. As such it would be stabler to define a custom ordering key

```
def custom_sorting(col: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    if col.name == "Duration":
        return col.round(2)
    else:
        return col.map({'PM':1,'failure':2})
```

Now new Event types can be introduced by expanding the dictonary and the rounding of Duration is also garanteed. You may use this custom sorting algorithm by calling `sort_values` as

```
machine_data.sort_values(by=['Duration', 'Event'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True,key=custom_sorting)
```